# What do I need to be careful of if I switch off ASP.NET's request validation?

Tags: asp.net, validation

My <textarea> forms will often, intentionally, include fragments of HTML, which my server code is correctly coded to handle. However, ASP.NET rejects any requests with HTML by causing an error:

```
"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client."
```

Accordingly, I've added two lines to my web.config in the system.web section:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

This allows the HTML through unhindered, but what else have I done? What other validations, if any, am I switching off that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't switch it off, I would suggest that you should encode/decode the html in your textarea on form submission instead .

A quick Google shows that Microsoft recommend exactly the same thing:

[Microsoft Docs: Request Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/request-validation)

> Request validation, a feature of ASP.NET since version 1.1, prevents the server from accepting content containing un-encoded HTML. This feature is designed to help prevent some script-injection attacks whereby client script code or HTML can be unknowingly submitted to a server, stored, and then presented to other users. We still strongly recommend that you validate all input data and HTML encode it when appropriate.